# Add CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS from the command line

Tags: c++, cmake, build, conan

I have a query concerning the utilization of compiler flags via the command line when utilizing Conan recipes. My objective is to employ the provided Conan recipes while having the flexibility to spontaneously add compiler flags from the command line.

I am seeking clarification on whether I might be making an error in my approach or if the -c flag is not intended for changing compiler flags as described. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Based on my understanding, this can be achieved using the -c flag in the conan install command. I attempted to do so with the argument -c tools.build:cflags="["/O1"]". However, upon inspecting my build logs, it became evident that the /O1 flag was not utilized during the compilation process.

Comment: Are you building c or c++ code? [cflags](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CFLAGS.html) is for c code

Answer (score 0):

Pass the following parameters to your CMake call:

```
CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
```

For example:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Wall" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wextra" ..
```